# Circle ci with heroku. Can't push to heroku automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, circleci

I am trying to set up a workflow that pushes to heroku after I push to my main branch on my github repo. I have done this before with a previous project. I copied over the circle.yml file and changed the name of the old app to the new app, but circle ci gets stuck on the line that says "      - git push git@heroku.com:my_app_name.git $CIRCLE_SHA1:refs/heads/master"

circle.yml

```
machine:
  ruby:
    version: 2.1.2
deployment:
  production:
    branch: master
    commands:
      - heroku maintenance:on --app my_app_name
      - heroku pg:backups capture --app my_app_name
      - git push git@heroku.com:my_app_name.git $CIRCLE_SHA1:refs/heads/master
      - heroku run rake db:migrate --app my_app_name
      - heroku maintenance:off --app my_app_name
  staging:
    branch: staging
    commands:
      - heroku maintenance:on --app my_app_name
      - git push git@heroku.com:my_app_name.git $CIRCLE_SHA1:refs/heads/master
      - heroku run rake db:migrate --app my_app_name
      - heroku maintenance:off --app my_app_name
```

I'm getting a remote rejected error at the line

```
      - git push git@heroku.com:my_app_name.git $CIRCLE_SHA1:refs/heads/master
```

I think I'm getting this error because "git@heroku.com:my_app_name.git" may not be correct. How do I find what to put here?

Answer (score 0):

`my_app_name` should be replaced by whatever app name is being used on Heroku.